# Magento - order email doesn't send for credit card payment

Tags: php, magento

I have a Magento install with a credit card order module (Atos). All the order confirmation emails are sending, except for the order by credit card number.

I'm new to Magento, and only know the transactionnal email templates about mailing and Magento. Where should I look to fix this?

Comment: When you place an order do you get any error message? When you log into the admin a look up an order place using credit card, does it state that email send or not send on that order?

Comment: backoffice order indicate that the customer is notified, and there's no error message during the sell

Comment: Do you use this extension:http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/atos-sips-extension-by-quadra-informatique.html ???

Comment: @AndreAusB right, i'm on the lastest version, 2.0.6

Answer (score 0):

You should figure out which one of the controllers is responsible for dealing with the CC payment.
Afterwards figure out the correct payment methode an if there is the following methode call:

```
if (!$order->getEmailSent()) {
                    $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
                }
```

Comment: This function is called in the right controller, in the 'success response code order'. I removed the 'if' to make a new test with the two functions called, but there's still no mail sent :(

Comment: ok, i put an echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert('functionName')</script>' at the beginning of every functions, and the only function's name popping out like this is redirectAction, just before landing on bank's page. Is this a normal behaviour ?

Comment: After the bank page, the user should be redirected to your magento shop an than your second alert should pop up and the mail should be send.

Comment: the bank payment page launched in production this morning, the email is sending perfectly... so it was a bug caused by the pre-production page, one way or another.